# How many ways to add up X numbers between 1 and 8 to get a sum Y, where order is important?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The numbers don't need to be distinct. It would also help, if someone would include the sum of all possible values of X, but I think I can solve that myself too. Thank you!

Comment: It's the coefficient of $u^Y$ in the expansion of $(u+u^2+\cdots+u^8)^X$. An application of the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, followed by some tedious algebraic manipulation involving the Binomial Theorem, should get you there. But this kind of question has been asked here dozens of times --- have a look around!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is order important (as in the title of question)? e.g. 3+4 is not the same as 4+3. He might then need to use the exponential generating function.

Comment: @user, I think you'll find that the coefficient of $u^7$ in $(u+u^2+\cdots+u^8)^2$ counts both the contribution from $u^3u^4$ and the contribution from $u^4u^3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess I'm confused about the phrase "order is important." What would be the difference if "order was not important"?

Comment: @user, my interpretation is that the number of ways to add two positive integers to get $3$ is $2$ if order counts (as $1+2$ is not the same as $2+1$ if order counts) but only $1$ if order doesn't count (as in that case $1+2$ is the same as $2+1$).

Comment: So, Andreas, any questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, for now I have no more questions. The part that confused me was counting all the contributions from the different orders. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good, Andreas. Then let me encourage you to write up and post an answer.